# GET request from postman does not trigger the API but browser does

Tags: postman, asp.net-apicontroller

When i try to hit the endpoint via the browser, it works just fine, however, when i try with postman it doesn't trigger the endpoint.

This is my json file with the launch URL.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51676",
      "sslPort": 44354
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "licent.Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
BROWSER -> http://localhost:5000/api/products (doesn't work)
POSTMAN -> http://localhost:5000/api/products (doesn't work)

BROWSER -> https://localhost:44354/api/product (WORKS)
POSTMAN -> https://localhost:44354/api/product (doesn't work)
```

I've noticed that the postman has some hidden headers by default, that could be the problem?
This is the error which I'm getting with the second URL

[image]

Hidden headers in postman
[image]

Comment: You can remove or uncheck those Headers and send the request. You would need the `host` as it wouldn't work without it. It looks like a certificate issue not the header you mentioned. You can also look in the general setting and allow the self signed cert option

Answer (score 0):

I will be answering my own question.

I found out that I have to disable the certificate and it works. I'm not sure if this is the way to go, but i assume until i will finish with the development, the certificate can be disabled.